# How can we convert an excel column to a row in datatable excel export?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, datatable

I have a table listing which is done with datatable and laravel. This table has 13 columns with 26000 raws. I am using server side datatable feature and I have implemented excel export feature of datatable also. My problem is from 13 columns 1 column is a comment (comment). May be it contains lengthy comments, so Can I add comment section as separate raw?

Please check the image given below. This is what I am expecting

**html**

```
<table id="booking_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.bookingNumber')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.comment')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.lastName')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.firstName')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.email')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.from')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.to')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.beds')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.dorms')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.sleeps')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.status')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.amount')</th>
                                    <th>@lang('cabinowner.answered')</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="1"  class="form-control input-sm search-input" placeholder="@lang('cabinowner.searchBoookingNo')"></th>
                                    <th id="2"></th>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    {{--<th><input type="text" id="3"  class="form-control input-sm search-input" placeholder="@lang('cabinowner.lastName')"></th>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="4"  class="form-control input-sm search-input" placeholder="@lang('cabinowner.firstName')"></th>--}}
                                    <th><input type="text" id="5"  class="form-control input-sm search-input" placeholder="@lang('cabinowner.SearchEmail')"></th>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm search-input" id="11">
                                            <option value="">(@lang('cabinowner.SearchStatus'))</option>
                                            <option value="1">@lang('cabinowner.bookingFix')</option>
                                            <option value="2">@lang('cabinowner.cancelled')</option>
                                            <option value="3">@lang('cabinowner.completed')</option>
                                            <option value="4">@lang('cabinowner.request')</option>
                                            <option value="5">@lang('cabinowner.bookingWaiting')</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
```

```
var booking_data;

        function fetch_data(is_date_search, daterange = ''){

            booking_data = $('#booking_data').DataTable({
                            "lengthMenu": [10, 50, 100, 250, 500],
                            "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "ajax": {
                                "url": '{{ route('cabinowner.bookings.datatables') }}',
                                "dataType": "json",
                                "type": "POST",
                                "data":{is_date_search:is_date_search, daterange:daterange}
                            },
                            "columns": [
                                { "data": "hash" },
                                { "data": "invoice_number" },
                                { "data": "comment" },
                                { "data": "usrLastname" },
                                { "data": "usrFirstname" },
                                { "data": "usrEmail" },
                                { "data": "checkin_from" },
                                { "data": "reserve_to" },
                                { "data": "beds" },
                                { "data": "dormitory" },
                                { "data": "sleeps" },
                                { "data": "status" },
                                { "data": "prepayment_amount" },
                                { "data": "answered" }
                            ],
                            "columnDefs": [
                                {
                                    "orderable": false,
                                    "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
                                }
                            ],
                            "language": {
                                "sEmptyTable":      "Keine Daten in der Tabelle vorhanden",
                                "sInfo":            "_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
                                "sInfoEmpty":       "0 bis 0 von 0 Einträgen",
                                "sInfoFiltered":    "(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)",
                                "sInfoPostFix":     "",
                                "sInfoThousands":   ".",
                                "sLengthMenu":      "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",
                                "sLoadingRecords":  "Wird geladen...",
                                "sProcessing":      "Bitte warten...",
                                "sSearch":          "Suchen",
                                "sZeroRecords":     "Keine Einträge vorhanden.",
                                "oPaginate": {
                                    "sFirst":       "Erste",
                                    "sPrevious":    "Zurück",
                                    "sNext":        "Nächste",
                                    "sLast":        "Letzte"
                                },
                                "oAria": {
                                    "sSortAscending":  ": aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren",
                                    "sSortDescending": ": aktivieren, um Spalte absteigend zu sortieren"
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        /* Visiblity disabled of "comment" column */
                        booking_data.column(2).visible( false );

                        /* Bottom buttons for datatables */
                        var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(booking_data, {
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                    extend: 'csv',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'excel',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
                                    }/*,
                                    customize: function (xlsx) {
                                        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                                        var col = $('col', sheet);
                                        $(col[1]).attr('width', 150);
                                    }*/
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'print',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
                                    }
                                },
                            ]
                        }).container().appendTo($('#buttons'));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Which package are you using for the excel export feature?

Comment: @kerrin, I am using datatable export feature

Comment: @samsam I had exactly the same issue, I instead used https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel and laravel queues since I was getting Nginx timeouts. With Laravel-Excel you can just pass the array directly from the database or format it to add the extra row. I know this doesn't exactly help  you but I was happy to get away from datatables and use PHP instead.

Comment: @DevinNorgarb, Thank you for this info.